# Why is it needed to know if a class is trivial or has trivial constructors?

Tags: c++

In type_traits you can check if a class is trivial, trivially copyable/moveable/constructable.

What is the point of knowing if it is? Is it to know if you can preform a member wise copy vs a bitwise copy? In essence, why is knowing that a class is trivial useful?

Comment: One reason is that it's unspecified (may be undefined) behavior to [memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) objects that are not trivially copyable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having class that is trivial you can just mem-copy object in memory. If object use i.g 32 bytes, you are taking these bytes and copy in other place. You have two same, usable objects. When you have non trivial class you cannot be sure if you copy you still have usable object. If it is not trivial you can't be certain if object can be copy this way( class can have some kind of handler i.g string and you would have two object that points to one data) . In addition if your class is also

```
std::is_standard_layout
```

then you can use this object in C programs.